# Sort within row in vim

Tags: sorting, vim

I've seen the standard way to sort rows in vim using `:sort`, but what if I don't want to sort rows, but instead what I want to do is sort columns. What I mean by this is say that I have the following three lines:

```
Each
Ate
Ana
```

I'd like each row to be sorted within itself. So that we would be left with

```
acEh
Aet
aAn
```

Is this possible using vim? Or would I need to create a quick python script to handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `global` you can split the line into characters, sort them and join back:

```
:%g/.*/s//\=submatch(0)->split('\zs')->sort('i')->join('')
```

will give:

```
acEh
Aet
Aan
```

Comment: Useful pointers: `:help :global`, `:help :s`, `:help sub-replace-special`, `:help submatch()`, `:help split()`, `:help sort()`, `:help join()`, `:help method`.